# Using Chef Inspec is it possible to verify the strength of SSH keys?

Tags: chef-infra, inspec

On executing the command `ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub` I am getting a output where the first few digits represent the key strength. Is there a possible way to validate the key strength using Chef inspec?

Suppose I get **1024......** as the output of the mentioned command, how do I check that it should be 1024 and not other values using Chef Inspec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the [command resource](https://docs.chef.io/inspec/resources/command) and [match](https://docs.chef.io/inspec/matchers/#be) its [output](https://docs.chef.io/inspec/resources/command/#stdout). something like the following should do the trick

```rb
describe command('ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub | awk '{print $1}) do
 its('exit_status') { should eq 0 }
 its('stdout') { should be >= 1024 }
end
```